I need help to develop multiple themes in my React App with Sass
I have structured my react app in this way:
i have palette-default.scss which contains variables for colors like
$surface: #0E0C19; etc...
i also have theme-default.scss
// Define, modify or overwrite bootstrap variables and color map (before Bootstrap import)

// Import palette theme colors
@import "../../palette-importer";

//Merge theme color map with new variables (to be able to use 'btn-<new-variable>', 'text-<new-variable>', etc.)
$theme-colors: (   
   "secondary":     $secondary,
   "success":       $success,
   "info":          $info,
   "warning":       $warning,
   "danger":        $danger,
   "light":         $light,
   "dark":          $dark,
   "primary":       $primary,
   "primary-100":   $primary-100,
   "primary-90":    $primary-90,
   "primary-80":    $primary-80,
   "primary-70":    $primary-70,   
   "primary-60":    $primary-60,
   "primary-50":    $primary-50,
   "primary-40":    $primary-40,
   "primary-30":    $primary-30,   
   "primary-20":    $primary-20,
   "primary-10":    $primary-10,
   "primary-5":     $primary-5,
   "accent":        $accent,
   "accent-80":     $accent-80,
   "accent-60":     $accent-60,
   "accent-40":     $accent-40,
   "accent-20":     $accent-20,
   "surface":       $surface,
   "surface-100":   $surface-100,
   "surface-90":    $surface-90,
   "surface-80":    $surface-80,
   "surface-70":    $surface-70,
   "surface-60":    $surface-60,
   "surface-50":    $surface-50,
   "surface-40":    $surface-40,
   "surface-30":    $surface-30,
   "surface-20":    $surface-20,
   "surface-10":    $surface-10,
   "surface-5":     $surface-5,
   "text-white":    $text-white,
   "text-primary":  $text-primary,
   "text-secondary":$text-secondary,
   "yellow":        $yellow,
   "yellow-100":    $yellow-100,
   "yellow-90":     $yellow-90,
   "yellow-80":     $yellow-80,
   "yellow-70":     $yellow-70,
   "yellow-60":     $yellow-60,
   "yellow-50":     $yellow-50,
   "yellow-40":     $yellow-40,
   "yellow-30":     $yellow-30,
   "yellow-20":     $yellow-20,
   "yellow-10":     $yellow-10,
   "yellow-5":      $yellow-5,
   "red":           $red,
   "red-100":       $red-100,
   "red-90":        $red-90,
   "red-80":        $red-80,
   "red-70":        $red-70,
   "red-60":        $red-60,
   "red-50":        $red-50,
   "red-40":        $red-40,
   "red-30":        $red-30,
   "red-20":        $red-20,
   "red-10":        $red-10,
   "red-5":         $red-5,
   "green":         $green,
   "green-100":     $green-100,
   "green-90":      $green-90,
   "green-80":      $green-80,
   "green-70":      $green-70,
   "green-60":      $green-60,
   "green-50":      $green-50,
   "green-40":      $green-40,
   "green-30":      $green-30,
   "green-20":      $green-20,
   "green-10":      $green-10,
   "green-5":       $green-5,
   "blue-custom":   $blue-custom,
   "blue-custom-dark":   $blue-custom-dark
);

$theme-colors: map-merge(
  (
    "primary":       $primary,
    "primary-100":   $primary-100,
    "primary-90":    $primary-90,
    "primary-80":    $primary-80,
    "primary-70":    $primary-70,   
    "primary-60":    $primary-60,
    "primary-50":    $primary-50,
    "primary-40":    $primary-40,
    "primary-30":    $primary-30,   
    "primary-20":    $primary-20,
    "primary-10":    $primary-10,
    "primary-5":     $primary-5,
    "accent":        $accent,
    "accent-80":     $accent-80,
    "accent-60":     $accent-60,
    "accent-40":     $accent-40,
    "accent-20":     $accent-20,
    "surface":       $surface,
    "surface-100":   $surface-100,
    "surface-90":    $surface-90,
    "surface-80":    $surface-80,
    "surface-70":    $surface-70,
    "surface-60":    $surface-60,
    "surface-50":    $surface-50,
    "surface-40":    $surface-40,
    "surface-30":    $surface-30,
    "surface-20":    $surface-20,
    "surface-10":    $surface-10,
    "surface-5":     $surface-5,
    "text-white":    $text-white,
    "text-primary":  $text-primary,
    "text-secondary":$text-secondary,
    "yellow":        $yellow,
    "yellow-100":    $yellow-100,
    "yellow-90":     $yellow-90,
    "yellow-80":     $yellow-80,
    "yellow-70":     $yellow-70,
    "yellow-60":     $yellow-60,
    "yellow-50":     $yellow-50,
    "yellow-40":     $yellow-40,
    "yellow-30":     $yellow-30,
    "yellow-20":     $yellow-20,
    "yellow-10":     $yellow-10,
    "yellow-5":      $yellow-5,
    "red":           $red,
    "red-100":       $red-100,
    "red-90":        $red-90,
    "red-80":        $red-80,
    "red-70":        $red-70,
    "red-60":        $red-60,
    "red-50":        $red-50,
    "red-40":        $red-40,
    "red-30":        $red-30,
    "red-20":        $red-20,
    "red-10":        $red-10,
    "red-5":         $red-5,
    "green":         $green,
    "green-100":     $green-100,
    "green-90":      $green-90,
    "green-80":      $green-80,
    "green-70":      $green-70,
    "green-60":      $green-60,
    "green-50":      $green-50,
    "green-40":      $green-40,
    "green-30":      $green-30,
    "green-20":      $green-20,
    "green-10":      $green-10,
    "green-5":       $green-5,
    "blue-custom":   $blue-custom
  ),
  $theme-colors
);

// Bootstrap 5 import
@import "../../bootstrap/bootstrap";

// If we use more than one theme, import here main-styles.scss file (this file - styles.default.scss need to be converted into *.css and saved in assets folder)

// If we use more than one theme, overwrite here styles which are specific only for this theme

and i have palette-importer.scss which is
@import 'sass/themes/palette-default.scss';

only imports the default palette.
I want to have multiple palettes for example palette-dark.scss and switch in my react app dinamically on click on button, how do i do that?
In my React App scss files for styling components i import the pallete-importer like @import ../../pallete-importer.scss. I want to dinamically switch between different palletes for the pallete-importer.scss to conditionaly import different palletes.
I don't undestand how to do that
